# How to 'disconnect' an element from grid?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

I have a website with some code-modules like the following. You can change the size over the grid-system from bootstrap. So thats why my grid is i the first line.
With my current code it looks like this:

```css
.label{
   background-color: #F0A;
   padding: 10px;
  }
 
 .image{
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 40px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
  <div class="content">
        <p class="label">Label</p>
        <div class="image">
           <p>Image</p>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I want it to look something like that:
[image]

I don't want to use grid inside of my module because it has to work in other sizes too. If that make sense. How can I kinda 'disconnect' my label from grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset display so it behaves as an inline boxe.

options of `display` can be : `inline`, `inline-block`, `inline-table`, `inline-flex`, `inline-grid` *and even `display:table` to keep block behavior but shrinking on content*.

`inline-block` seems to be the most commun option used and compatible since ever.

```css
.label{
   background-color: #F0A;
   padding: 10px;
   display:inline-block;
  }
 
 .image{
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 40px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
  <div class="content">
        <p class="label">Label</p>
        <div class="image">
           <p>Image</p>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If `display` is not what you want, then `float:left;` works too

```css
.label{
   background-color: #F0A;
   padding: 10px;
   float:left;
  }
 
 .image{
 clear:both; /* clear the float */
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 40px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
  <div class="content">
        <p class="label">Label</p>
        <div class="image">
           <p>Image</p>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several solution : 
You can give a width to your label like `width: 10%;`

Or better way you create a new row :

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
  <div class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 offset-sm-9">
           <p class="label">Label</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
           <div class="image">
              <p>Image</p>
           </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Both not works for me. When I use a larger text than "label" the <div> is too short. The <div> hav to orientate on my <p>.